# Get logged in content using PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

I try to get content of logged in pages with below code. I tried different URLs it work but for this one I'm not sure why it returned blank result. I checked the error log, nothing were shown, and my curl is enabled.

```
solved
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some misconfiguration in your curl settings, first:

```
$login = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $pass,
    'login' => 'login'
);
```

This should have only the fields you want to post, so `'login' => 'login'` is irrelevant.
Fields names must match the form fields names, otherwise they will be no meaning to server. You can check their names by Firebug or inspect element.

Second:

```
$loginUrl = 'https://affiliate.styles.my/index.php/login/page/login';
```

Since you are posting a `form`, you should post to the url that is set in `action` attribute, you can find this by firing inspect element in FireFox, and inspect the `form` tag, then see what is the url `action` attribute points to.

Try this:

```
<?php
$username = 'eldy';
$pass = '1234';

$login = array(
    'user' => $username,
    'password' => $pass
);

$loginUrl = 'https://affiliate.styles.my/index.php/login/dologin';
echo http_build_query($login);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($login));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://affiliate.styles.my/index.php/dashboard/page/dashboard");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

$content2 = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content2;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: @AmyJohnson I was about to test it. but I found the password changed :D.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your login post url isn't correct. The actual form post url is

```
        $loginUrl = 'https://affiliate.styles.my/index.php/login/dologin';
```

Apart from that the form post fields are not set correctly, the password field should be 'pass' not 'password'

```
$login = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'pass' => $pass,
    'login' => 'login'
);
```

So the right way to do this will be
First load the login page
send the post data
and then fetch dashboard page
Here is the correct code

```
<?php

$username = 'eldy';
$pass = '1234';

$login = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'pass' => $pass,
    'login' => 'login'
);

            $loginUrl = 'https://affiliate.styles.my/index.php/login/dologin';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://affiliate.styles.my/index.php/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_exec($ch);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

var_dump($ch);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $content;





curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://affiliate.styles.my/index.php/dashboard/page/dashboard");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$content2 = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content2;
curl_close($ch);
```